# How to rename a Network volume's name in WOW64 Apps' Common File Dialog

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, wow64, filedialog, common-dialog

I'm developing a network redirector like SMB.

Once a volume has been connected, I create 4 registry keys to following nodes.

- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2\#UNCPATH
- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2\##UNCPATH
- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2\#Z:
- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2\Z:

> Key: "_LabelFromReg"
>   value: "The Disk Name I Want"

Then, it works well in all apps of 32bit Windows XP, Vista, 7.
And it works in 64bit Windows Explorer too.

But for the WOW64 application's file open dialogs, it doesn't work.(eg. MS Office 2007)

Why can't wow64 apps show the name I put?
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

32-bit and 64-bit applications get a different view of the registry in 64-bit Win 7.  See details here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384182%28VS.85%29.aspx